# Is there a performance advantage in how I express a mathematical formula

Tags: performance, math, polynomial-math

I have an algebra problem with a lot of variables that I cannot simplify.  Are there performance considerations to how I express it in code?  The formula is:

[image: E=(X * (A-AC-F-M) * (1-L) - R) / (A)]

I could multiply it out, divide the `A`, and do a lot to make it look different, but I not simpler.  What should I consider when I write it in code?  I will be implementing this in both javascript and .NET.

Comment: not really......  Actually, is this happening in a loop? Could part of it be lifted out of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

There are performance implications in general, but usually it's not a bottleneck. In this case if you factor A out to get

E = X * (1-C) * (1-L) - (X * (F+M) * (1-L) + R) / A

your operation could will actually increase.

Generally performance tuning of this sort should be saved for the last step, and always combined with profiling and timing. Optimizing algorithms and data structures is much more important.

Comment: Could you explain why this will have better performance than the way I expressed it?

Comment: It won't -- it should take about 6 cycles longer. That's why I don't recommend changing it in that fashion.

Comment: How are you determining how many cycles it takes in both ways?

Comment: So you've gone from 2 muls + 5 adds, to 4 muls + 6 adds?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important consideration in this case should be readability and clarity.

Performance will be more than adequate.  This is a trivially simple calculation that would not be a bottleneck even if you called it billions of times.  Time it in a loop and prove it to yourself.